# Playing Different Audio Files based on Scroll Position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, audio

I have a website where I want different audio clips to play at different scroll positions. With the current code, the audio switches but then keeps restarting everytime I move the scrollbar. How can I tell it to play the audio only when it hits the certain scroll position?

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 20213 && scroll_pos < 36041) { //strozzi   
                $("audio").attr("src", "audio/Strozzi.mp3");
            } 
            else if(scroll_pos > 36041 && scroll_pos < 51097){ //Leonarda
                $("audio").attr("src", "audio/Leonarda.mp3");
            }
            else {
                $("audio").attr("src", "audio/Hildegard.mp3");//Hildegard
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within your condition

```
scroll_pos > 20213 && scroll_pos < 36041
```

will be `true` for **all** values between **20213** and **36041**, so while you are between these values and you scroll, the condition gets triggered over and over again.

What you need is some way to check if the file that is connected to that scroll position is already playing.

You could for example add a `data` attribute to your `<audio>` tag that gets updated in your condition:

```
if(scroll_pos > 20213 && scroll_pos < 36041 && $("audio").data('playing') !== 'Strozzi.mp3') { // Check if the file is already playing
    $("audio")
       .attr("src", "audio/Strozzi.mp3")
       .data('playing', 'Strozzi.mp3'); // save the currently playing file in the attribute `data-playing`
}
```

Comment: This makes sense! That's what I figured happened. What do you mean by add a data attribute to my audio tag? What would that look like?

Comment: What do you mean? I wrote that code in my answer  `.data('playing', 'Strozzi.mp3'); `